# How do I invalidate canvas of an object owned by another thread?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to load data in a separate thread and than to call `redraw` method to invalidate canvas and draw the data. However, when I call `redraw` method, it triggers breakpoint with following message:

> ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by different thread..."

I'm looking for some sort of dispatch method that could be used to call the function in the correct thread.

What is the proper way to do this is Qt5?

Comment: See:  https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads

Comment: @JeremyFriesner thanks! I'm really new to Qt. Could you point me to some example that would show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is to send a signal from worker thread back to the main thread which then triggers the redraw. Something like this (I haven't tested it):

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ...
    void loadData()
    {
        ... // Do stuff

        emit dataLoaded();
    }
}

class MainWindow : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow()
    {
        Worker *worker = new Worker;
        worker->moveToThread(workerThread);
        connect(&workerThread, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::loadData);
        connect(worker, &Worker::dataLoaded, this, &MainWindow::redraw);
        workerThread.start();
    }

public slots:
    void redraw()
    {
        // Do your redrawing here
    }

private:
    QThread workerThread;
}
```